# Itext 5.5.9 - Issue while setting encryption

Tags: java, itext

I am getting the below exception while setting encryption for a pdf.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive
```

Below is the code -

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

    HashMap<String, String> info = reader.getInfo();
    info.put("Title", "Accessible Itext PDF");
    info.put("Subject", "Itext PDF");
    info.put("Keywords", "Itext");
    info.put("Creator", "Me");
    info.put("Author", "Me");
    stamper.setMoreInfo(info);
    stamper.setEncryption(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(),OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);

    PdfContentByte pagecontent;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {
        pagecontent = stamper.getOverContent(++i);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(pagecontent, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                new Phrase(String.format("page %s of %s", i, n)), 550, 20, 0);
    }

    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

I have added itext 5.5.9, bcprov-jdk16-146, bcmail-jdk16-146, bctsp-jdk16-146 jars externally but i am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The class `org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive` is part of `bcprov-ext-jdk16`. Dowload this add it to your classpath and the error should go away.

You can download it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk16/1.46)

Comment: @CoolKicks You are sure it is excetly the same class which is missing?

Comment: Thanks @jens ..I got it working by replacing Itext 5.5.9 with Itext 5.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it working..

Seems like there was an issue with itext 5.5.9 jar. i replaced it with itext 5.2.1 and it worked fine.

Comment: Replacing a fairly current itext 5.5.9 by an ancient itext 5.2.1 is a giant step back, both feature-wise and bugfix-wise. This can hardly be called a solution.

Comment: I cant get it to work by using 5.5.9...U got any ideas?

Comment: According to the [itext 5.5.9 pom.xml](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/298d35b11b37031120d3804f922127cde46a4d15/itext/pom.xml) that version relies on Bouncy Castle version 1.49, and there have been major changes between BC 1.46 and BC 1.49. Thus, I would propose updating your BC jars.